# chartView: axis values change on Zooming

Tags: c++, qt, charts, pyqt5, qml

I have a simple chart view in my Qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
            XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: chartView.zoomReset();
        }
    }
}
```

I use a rectangle to zoom in it.:

```
var r = Qt.rect(x, y, w, h)
chartView.zoomIn(r)
```

And its working grate! But problem is when user zoom inside of the chart the values in axis changes. And new values are shifted a little bit.
So when user wants to zoom on a value and range of the values are very big, user lose the specific value that he wants to zoom in it.

The main problem is because ticks are not based on values... they are based on max and min of the range

```
(max - min)/ticks = new ticks on the axis
```

I need to fix them on numbers so that even with 10 or more zoom's in the plot ticks remain on values.

Comment: have you tried : `animationOptions:ChartView.GridAxisAnimations`

Comment: yes . but it just set some animation on grid changing . not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set ticks based on values, according to this documentation [qml-qtcharts-valueaxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-valueaxis.html) :

tickType : ValueAxis.TicksDynamic : Ticks are placed according to tickAnchor and tickInterval values

```
ValueAxis {
    id: axisX
    min: 0
    max: 10
    tickCount: 5

    tickAnchor: 1
    tickInterval: 1
    tickType : ValueAxis.TicksDynamic
}
```

so just set tickInterval and tickAnchor and the ticks are based on values on the axis.